# How to use one component twice for the other tab using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, i want to make a switching tab for full time and part time job.

while clicking on the `full time job` it should show min and max range  - i have created that. but when we click on `Part-time job` it should show different min and max range. How to display the min and max range for part time with the same component but values varies.

for part time: min -

```
"$20,000",
  "$30,000",
  "$40,000",
  "$50,000",
  "$60,000",
  "$70,000",
  "$80,000",
  "$90,000"
```

max:

```
"$30,000",
  "$40,000",
  "$50,000",
  "$60,000",
  "$70,000",
  "$80,000",
  "$90,000",
  "$100,000"
```

Here is the code for min and Max:

```
import React from "react";
import { List, Input, Form, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";

const minOptions = [
  "$40,000",
  "$60,000",
  "$80,000",
  "$100,000",
  "$120,000",
  "$140,000",
  "$160,000",
  "$180,000"
];
const maxOptions = [
  "$60,000",
  "$80,000",
  "$100,000",
  "$120,000",
  "$140,000",
  "$160,000",
  "$180,000"
];

class Select extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeMenu: " ",
    open: true,
    min: "",
    max: "",
    rangeValue: ""
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { min, max } = this.state;
    if (min !== prevState.min || max !== prevState.max) {
      this.setState({
        rangeValue: `${min} - ${max}`
      });
    }
  }

  toggleMenu = e => {
    this.setState({
      activeMenu: e.target.name
    });
  };

  changeValue = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  toggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { open: !prevState.open };
    });
  };

  getMenuOptions = () => {
    let options = [];
    switch (this.state.activeMenu) {
      case "min": {
        options = minOptions;
        break;
      }
      case "max": {
        options = maxOptions;
        break;
      }
      default:
        break;
    }
    return options.map((option, i) => {
      return (
        <List
          key={i}
          onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(this, this.state.activeMenu, option)}
        >
          {option}
        </List>
      );
    });
  };

  handleSelect = (menu, value) => {
    this.setState({
      [menu]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { open, min, max, activeMenu } = this.state;
    const menuOptions = this.getMenuOptions();
    return (
      <Segment compact className="myRange">
        <Input
          icon="caret down"
          onClick={this.toggleOpen}
          placeholder="Rate Range"
          value={this.state.rangeValue}
        />

        {open && (
          <div>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group className="myRange">
                <Form.Input
                  placeholder="Min"
                  name="min"
                  value={min}
                  onFocus={this.toggleMenu}
                  onChange={this.changeValue}
                />
                &mdash;
                <Form.Input
                  className="myValues"
                  placeholder="Max"
                  name="max"
                  value={max}
                  onFocus={this.toggleMenu}
                  onChange={this.changeValue}
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
            <div>
              <ul className={activeMenu}>{menuOptions}</ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Segment>
    );
  }
}
export default Select;
```

here is the working one: "https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-fire-8sfug"

Is it possible to give Min and Max value for full time and part time in one component? If yes, then Can anyone help me in this?

Can anyone help me in making as shown in snapshot? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your sandbox appears to work for a single option. Are you simply asking how to use some "toggle" to conditionally render one or the other of your `Select` components?

Comment: @DrewReese - Yes, Correct. I want it in one component, in codesandbox the min value starts from $40,000 and Max value from $60, 000  - i want the same thing for parttime also.

Comment: pass minOption and maxOption as a props from full-time and part-time compoent. In select compoent, use the props values and keep the default props as a initails values

Comment: @ganeshphirke - but there are different values for part time. i have mentioned above in my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a super elegant solution, but accomplishes I believe what you are after without unmounting/mounting each `Select`. This avoids them losing their internal states.

Use some state to store which option is displayed, conditionally hide the `Select` component not being viewed. Loft the fulltime/partime options to the parent to be passed to each select individually. Previously these values where in file scope, but now need to be polled from props, `this.props.minOptions`.

```
const ftOptions = {
  minOptions: [...],
  maxOptions: [...]
};

const ptOptions = {
  minOptions: [...],
  maxOptions: [...]
};

function App() {
  const [ftSelected, setFtSelected] = useState(true);

  const toggleButton = () => setFtSelected(t => !t);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button.Group>
        <Button primary active={ftSelected} onClick={toggleButton}>
          Full-time
        </Button>
        <Button active={!ftSelected} onClick={toggleButton}>
          Part-time
        </Button>
      </Button.Group>

      <div style={{ display: ftSelected ? "initial" : "none" }}>
        <Select
          maxOptions={ftOptions.maxOptions}
          minOptions={ftOptions.minOptions}
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: !ftSelected ? "initial" : "none" }}>
        <Select
          maxOptions={ptOptions.maxOptions}
          minOptions={ptOptions.minOptions}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit sparkling-rain-rdckg]

Comment: Thanks for providing solution to my query, but I couldn't able to find out whether the value i'm giving for full time or part time as per the codesandbox.

Comment: @Sanjana I don't understand you mean in this comment?

Comment: I mean i could not able to figure it out whether i'm giving values for Full-time tab or i'm giving value for part-time tab. After giving values when i click on the part-time tab, i'm getting the same value. Do i need to create another select Component for the part-time tab because the min and max values varies for the part-time tab.

Comment: The buttons are active for the "tab" you are working in. Oh, I see, you also want different min/max values.

Comment: @Sanjana Updated answer and sandbox. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Even i'm so sorry for making you confuse. I should learn to write my query in a clear way :)

Comment: HI, i wonder if this is a child component then how do i pass range value to the parent component. can you  help me in this?

Comment: @Sanjana If you are asking how `App` can get the current selected values of a `Select` component, this is typically achieved with a callback, i.e. `onChange`, that is also passed to the child component.

Comment: Yes, i want to get only the range value from Select component. Here  i've done in this way "https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-heisenberg-vm4l3"

Comment: @Sanjana You'll need to expose out from `Select` an onChange (or similar) callback to pass out the updated min/max from `componentDidUpdate`. I updated my linked sandbox.

Comment: Resse - Hi, Can i have a class Component example because i'm not much familiar with hooks concept. Could you please help me in this ?

Comment: @Sanjana Sure, which part(s)?

Comment: Only App.js component